# AJAX: What's the best way to show the user that the requested content is loading?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, navigation

Should i use the traditional "rotating gif" on a semi transparent overlay? Or should i use a top loading bar, like YouTube and Instagram do?

I'm talking about the websites, not the native apps. Thanks!

Comment: As a user i personally like a loading bar showing the percentage of the page loaded. This helps the user to understand if the page refresh is required when there is performance related issue

Comment: It depends on too many factors to give a useful answer. I voted to close this because it's far too broad.

Comment: @jazZRo The question seems to be pretty simple, actually. There's just too options and i'm asking which of them is the best. Of course i would appreciate getting some references like researches and so on... I don't understand why you think it's far too broad.

Comment: Every site will have different answers. It depends on context, content, users, aesthetics etc. Also it is not clear why you rely on just those two options as there are many ways to communicate that content is loading or needs to load first.

Comment: Pro tip: Make sure it is visible and doesn't have too many bells and whistles

Comment: Another pro tip: Put it in a noticeable place. The system I work on has a loader bar across the top of the page that's outside the user's immediate focus. We're switching to spinners on the particular widgets that are loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of traditional infinite loader, try using a content preview mode. This gives user better feedback of what's going on, and where on the UI data is loading.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's down to the site you're displaying it on. Certain types of sites will require certain types of loading/progress bars. Check these out for a bit of inspiration but make sure the design matches the content of the site or page.
https://designmodo.com/progress-bars/

Also keep in mind the users of the site - what is their general persona and what would you think they'd prefer to see? Basically, make it relervent.